# Salesforce Apex Response Headers

Tags: rest, salesforce, apex

I am trying to add a content-length header to my rest response as it's coming back 'chunked'.

```js
 @HttpGet
  global static RESTBase getCatalog() {
   RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
   RestResponse resp = RestContext.response;
   Map < String, string > respHeader = new Map < String, string > ();

   String storeId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
   Store__c currentStore = QueryUtils.getStoreFromStoreNumber(storeId);
   if (currentStore == null) {
     CatalogResponse catalogResponse = new CatalogResponse();

     catalogResponse.Status = '404';

     return catalogResponse;
   }

   Map < String, PricebookEntry > priceBookEntries = getPriceBookEntriesForPriceBook(currentStore.Price_Book__c);
   List < TriCom__Category__c > rootCategories = getRootProductCategories();
   Map < String, List < UPC_Code__c >> upcCodeMap = getUPCCodeMap();

   RESTCatalog catalog = new RESTCatalog();

   catalog.PriceBookId = currentStore.Price_Book__c;
   catalog.StoreNumber = currentStore.Name;
   catalog.Categories = createRestCategory(rootCategories, upcCodeMap, priceBookEntries);
       
   String returnJson = JSON.serialize(catalog);
       
   resp.addHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(returnJson.length()));

   return catalog;
 }
```

When I do a get request I get back:

```
"errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
"message": "System.InvalidHeaderException: Header name \"Content-Length\" is not allowed.\\\n\\\n(System Code)\
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to set the content-length, it'll be set for you by the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce will set content-length automatically.  It is actually documented that this header cannot be set.